# How to edit remote files (on a guest machine in vagrant) using an editor installed on the host?

Tags: remote-access

I use vagrant in windows and work with linux boxes, sometimes i need to edit a file that is not in the shared vagrant folder, like apache2 config files. I don't like using a command line editor like nano or vim.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use your own IDE(like PHPstorm) you may connect via sftp by setting it up on your on your IDE, pointing to the root directory('/'). You should also check if the user is connecting to have the right access to the file, much better if you can allow 'root' to connect remotely to your vagrant box.